# Filebeat not starting TCP server (input)

Tags: filebeat

So I have configured filebeat to accept input via TCP. This is filebeat.yml file.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: tcp
  host: ["localhost:9000"]
  max_message_size: 20MiB
```

For some reason filebeat does not start the TCP server at port 9000. I have verified this using wireshark. Wireshark shows nothing at port 9000.

This is output of command "filebeat -e -d "*"" run on terminal

```
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    instance/beat.go:468    Home path: [/usr/local/Cellar/filebeat/6.2.4] Config path: [/usr/local/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/local/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/usr/local/var/log/filebeat]
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:495    Beat metadata path: /usr/local/var/lib/filebeat/meta.json
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    instance/beat.go:475    Beat UUID: 764da0fd-ea93-4777-b1ea-63149be0d6b6
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    instance/beat.go:213    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.2.4
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:230    Initializing output plugins
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    DEBUG   [processors]    processors/processor.go:49      Processors: 
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    pipeline/module.go:76   Beat name: Ad-MBP.domain
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    ERROR   fileset/modules.go:95   Not loading modules. Module directory not found: /usr/local/Cellar/filebeat/6.2.4/module
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:97   Starting metrics logging every 30s
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    INFO    instance/beat.go:301    filebeat start running.
2019-08-14T09:12:40.745-0600    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:90       Registry file set to: /usr/local/var/lib/filebeat/registry
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:110      Loading registrar data from /usr/local/var/lib/filebeat/registry
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:121      States Loaded from registrar: 0
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    WARN    beater/filebeat.go:261  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:48   Loading Prospectors: 1
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:152      Starting Registrar
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    DEBUG   [cfgfile]       cfgfile/reload.go:95    Checking module configs from: /usr/local/etc/filebeat/modules.d/*.yml
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    DEBUG   [cfgfile]       cfgfile/reload.go:109   Number of module configs found: 0
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:82   Loading and starting Prospectors completed. Enabled prospectors: 0
2019-08-14T09:12:40.746-0600    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:127   Config reloader started
2019-08-14T09:12:40.748-0600    DEBUG   [cfgfile]       cfgfile/reload.go:151   Scan for new config files
2019-08-14T09:12:40.748-0600    DEBUG   [cfgfile]       cfgfile/reload.go:170   Number of module configs found: 0
2019-08-14T09:12:40.748-0600    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:219   Loading of config files completed.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I believe filebeat inputs are only available from filebeat 6.3+, anything older used filebeat prospectors.

6.3 TCP input documentation, nothing available for 6.2 or older as it uses prospectors:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.3/filebeat-input-tcp.html

Your logs show that you are on filebeat version 6.24, could you try out your configuration with 6.3+?